# Javascript - Push an Array into array in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have problem to push some value that assigned to be an array in the object

Here my code :

```
var hasil = [{  product: 'listBarang[i][0]',
                shoppers: [],
                leftOver: 'listBarang[i][2]',
                totalProfit: 0
            }]
```

What I think is using push method like below

```
hasil.shoppers.push('test')
```

But it give me an error like this

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Is anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: `hasil[0].shoppers.push('test')`, because `hasil` is an `array`, which contains the `object`. So to edit your question title: 'Push a value into an Array in an Object in an Array'. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hasil` is an array of objects, so if you want to maniputate on those objects, you need to access them directly i.e. with `hasil[0]`:

```
hasil[0].shoppers.push('test')
```